# How to change the color of RecyclerView item, if this item is clicked before?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `recyclerView` with a custom layout (1 `imageView` + 2 `TextViews`)..

The question : The Text of `recyclerView` item is in Green.. I need to change it to Red , if the user has clicked the item in `recyclerView`.

```
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView title,desc;
    public ImageView thumbnail;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        desc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        whereToGo = title.getText().toString();
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {


        Intent i = new Intent(mContext, DisplayLockedLesson.class);
        i.putExtra("Lesson Name", title.getText().toString());
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        mContext.startActivity(i);

        }

    }
}
```

SO, I'm Making Lessons App .. When the user clicked the item of the `recyclerView`, it changes the color of this item telling the user that he finished the lesson before ...

Thanks .

Answer (score 4):

Create a variable that will store the position of the clicked textview and declare it globally.

```
private int clickedTextViewPos=-1;
```

In viewholder whenever position is clicked set that position as clicked and
                call notifyDataSetChanged()

notifyDataSetChanged() - this notifies the adapter that data is changed.

```
private class YourViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public YourViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            clickedTextViewPos = getAdapterPosition();
            notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
         });
      }
 }
```

In the onBindViewHolder if the position is equal show text color in red or else in green.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if(clickedTextViewPos==position){
            edtUser.setTextColor(edtUser.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
    }else {
            edtUser.setTextColor(edtUser.getContext().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.green));
    }
}
```

Comment: 50% worked... When i click the item of Recyclerview.. it is changed to red.. but other items are also changed to red ...

Comment: how?if you follow the code it should work...clickedTextViewPos should be global variable

Answer (score 1):

I think you may add a flag to each item either in a hashmap or to a database.
Change this flag in the item onclicklistener method...then you can read this flag to change the color of this item.

Comment: Please can u tell me how to Flag recyclerView Clicked Item ?

Comment: You may create a hashmap with the item number and its condition.
Save its condition to checked or not checked inside the onclick item method.
Inside your recyclerview adapter select the color according to condition.

I can help you more if you can show your adapter code.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the model of recyclerview take a boolean isChecked and on basis of that you can set the colour .

Comment: This should be in comment! Anyway this solution is perfect, to save last clicked item of recycler view in to model class and changing background accordingly.